# How to select text in terminal? (linux debian)

Tags: linux, debian, terminal

sometimes I got more than 3000 lines in the terminal and I need copy all them, I'm wondering how can I "select all" content in Debian terminal?
when click Edit -->Select All from the terminal, this closed the terminal !! any help, please?

Answer (score 2):

If this is output from a single command, pipe to `xclip -i`. Or, even better, redirect to some file, continue processing it in a pipe, etc. The Unix commandline is inteded to be used with pipes and redirections, you don't need to cut and paste.

If you got 3000 lines that are not the output of a single command, I'd like to hear some details :-)

Some more details (what kind of command produces the output, where do you want to paste it into, etc.) would have helped to understand the problem better in the first place.

Comment: the output of my project in college